# Unit Testing in Mockito, Calling a chain of functions on an object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I've not done much testing and very minimal in Mockito. When I call delete on a certain object, I get a `DeleteResponse`. This has a method called `getProcessingErrors()` which is a set. I can then call `.isEmpty()` to see if there are errors or not. I'm trying to mock this out.

```
DeleteResponse deleteResponse = mock(DeleteResponse.class);

when(catalogFramework.delete(any(DeleteRequest.class))).thenReturn(deleteResponse);

when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(new HashSet<ProcessingDetails>());

PowerMockito.when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors().isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

#### Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by getProcessingErrors()
getProcessingErrors() should return Set
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Now, from the way I am reading this, it is saying `isEmpty` cannot return a boolean, but I believe it's cutting out early and just looking at the getProcessingErrors. How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you mocking the actual response and then testing that itself. your test case will always evaluate to true. which class and which method are you testing?

Comment: Well sometimes I want isEmpty to be true and sometimes I want it to be false. Then I can just throw that one line in each test. No?

Answer (score 3):

You need mock `deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()` object before mock `isEmpty()` function

```
when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(mockObject);
PowerMockito.when(mockObject.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In here

```
when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(new HashSet<ProcessingDetails>());

PowerMockito.when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors().isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

Either return Set with at least 1 element so that it returns true and **you don't need the second line** or Mock the HashSet also to return true when `isEmpty()` is called.

Without `HashSet` mocking

```
Set<ProcessingDetails> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new ProcessingDetails());
when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(set);
```

With `HashSet` mocking

```
HashSet<ProcessingDetails> mockedSet = mock(HashSet.class);
when(mockedSet.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Mockito's [`RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) to eliminate the need to mock the intermediate object:

```
DeleteResponse deleteResponse = mock(DeleteResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

when(catalogFramework.delete(any(DeleteRequest.class))).thenReturn(deleteResponse);

when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors().isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

Although in this case, using `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` isn't really necessary... you can just initialize an empty `HashSet` and return it as follows:

```
when(deleteResponse.getProcessingErrors()).thenReturn(new HashSet<>());
```

This `HashSet` is empty, so it will return your desired result of `true` when calling `isEmpty()`.

Comment: Can this be used in conjunction with PowerMockito?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use this with PowerMockito in the way I described above.